# How would you judge the alignment of this action and the possible repercussions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

I'm playing a chaotic good cleric in a Pathfinder campaign!
I would like to know your opinion about something that happened during our last session.

After we defeated a group of trolls, we returned to the mayor of the village to report this feat and to ask for a reward.
The mayor said that he could give us a reward of 500 gp, taken from the tax revenues of the entire year.
Since I wanted to give the money to the local parson in order to help him fix the roof of the church of Desna (80 gp), and the rest to the citizens, I suggested to the mayor that he return the remaining tax money (minus the 80 gp) to the people himself.
The mayor suspiciously agreed, but I didn't trust him.
I decided to announce to the people that the mayor was going to give the money to them instead, in order to put him on the spot.

Is this behaviour congruent with my current alignment?

Also, let's say that the mayor refuses to return the money and the people begin riotting against the authority or, worse, they kill said authority. Am I responsible for this?

Is fomenting a riot for good causes congruent with a CG pg?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: This is both unclear (which system?  D&D alignments? You say Desna so I'm guessing Pathfinder) and purely opinion-based - everyone's personal take on what's LE vs CG vs whatever is completely different and also not super relevant.  Is the problem that your DM is dinging you for this? Is the problem that you're not sure if your action is congruent with CG (where I would argue that alignment should describe your character's personality, not be some weird guideline you follow)?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. This discussion was between me and the other players. The DM is not changing my alignment or anything.

Comment: @Gwyn Unfortunately for this question, this site doesn't lend itself to discussion. If you're looking for outside feedback in order to continue or expand the discussion beyond your playing group, what you're looking for is a forum, not a Q&A site.

Comment: It might be possible to give an objective answer by comparing the situation with the definitions of each alignment in the Pathfinder rulebook, but I'm told they're a bit vague. Sounds like you're probably going to need a meta to get it re-opened, if you care that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds **chaotic good** to me, so I'd say you were playing your alignment.

You're trying to make sure that the church is repaired and the people get their money, which is *good*, but you're doing so in a way that doesn't respect the existing power structure or etiquette - just yelling it out in front of a crowd as opposed to discussing with the mayor or other officials - which seems *chaotic*, especially if your character believes that their actions may cause a riot.

Answer (score -3):

### The Initial Question

Assuming D&D/Pathfinder's 3x3 alignment system, I would call this a **Lawful Good** action, although a bit mean to the mayor.

It's Good because you helped others at the cost of your own benefit. You gave up 420gp so that each citizen could get a few silver, which is unlikely to get you particularly improved treatment in town.

It's Lawful because you promoted honorable/honest behavior and did so in a completely legal and reasonable way. A Lawful person would consider it the mayor's responsibility to keep his word, and informing the population would be using the social systems of the town to enforce that requirement.

Chaos is tempting, since you're potentially thumbing your nose at authority, but I wouldn't call the act itself chaotic: after all, the mayor was already going to lose that 500gp, so you haven't hurt him unless he was going to steal it for himself.

It's always worth remembering that your alignment isn't a straitjacket and you can perform acts that go against it without shifting your alignment unless it becomes a pattern. A Chaotic Neutral person might totally do what you did just because it was fun and worth losing the money to see the look on the mayor's face.

### Fomenting a Riot

This shoves the act heavily **Chaotic Neutral** and probably toward **Chaotic Evil**. Riots are chaotic in nature and don't follow law. They also don't tend to have good outcomes. You point out that the crowd might kill the mayor. Killing someone for not wanting to give up reasonable taxes (500gp in a year is a tiny amount per capita) is not a proportionate punishment; the mayor here is not a villain to be slain. The risk of evil acts and the destructive effects this would have on the town and its people make it so that CE feels like the best description of the situation. It's not burning an orphanage, but it's on the same spectrum.

Comment: -1 after the edit: Did I miss the population of the town somewhere? 500gp seems like a lot of tax revenue to me. Even a few silvers would be a nice help for most families. If a riot is caused by outrage against an evil act, then it's not necessarily evil.

Comment: This neatly demonstrates why the question is off-topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not neatly enough. Please elaborate. Seems to me like it demonstrates that the format is working, so I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: @DCShannon That it's merely matter of opinion and will only lead to debate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's unfortunate you're not in chat right now. That's not debate, that's feedback on the reason why I downvoted, which is that I think he's wrong, which is why I would downvote any answer on any question. There are actually a limited number of answers here (9), so we'll vote and the one with the most votes is right. So far lawful good is not winning, but then again the question is closed so we only have two options. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @DCShannon A popularity contest won't make one of the answers objectively correct. The question (like most alignment questions) can only ever be opinion-based.

Comment: Just so. When everyone has an opinion on something and nobody agrees on how to interpret it, like with alignment, there's no possibility of a question on it being objectively answerable.

Comment: @DCShannon - Fair enough; I incorrectly read "town" instead of "village." I don't think the result particularly changes if it's 3sp or 2gp. A few days' inn fees  a nice windfall for a villager, but it's not "a feast for the adventurers" level of bribery.